# Select column names with their maximum data length MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table in mysql with many columns and I want to see maximum length of values. My purpose is that I do know that some of data is truncated when insert and I want to increase varchar length. But do not know, what columns. (Explanation little messy, but probably sql will make sense)

I tried:

```
 select COLUMN_NAME, CHARACTER_MAXIMUM_LENGTH, DATA_TYPE, (SELECT LENGTH(COLUMN_NAME) as maxlen FROM my_database.my_table ORDER BY  maxlen DESC LIMIT 1)
from information_schema.columns
where table_schema = 'my_database' AND
      table_name = 'my_table'AND DATA_TYPE = 'varchar'
```

It works, but return the length of the column, but not data inside it. (I.e. id column is called `id`, I got 2).

If I use JOIN (`ON TRUE` condition), I got error that COLUMN_NAME is undefined.

Stored procedures does not allow for data return, and function does not allow dynamic sql inside it.

How to tell MySQL (in case of my query) to consider  COLUMN_NAME not as a string, but as column name? If this is not, possible in select, how to get columns with maximum data inside them?

Desired result looks like:

```
column_1     |     25      |   varchar    | 20
column_2     |     25      |   varchar    | 7
```

I am interested only in varchar, as int does not make sense to adjust (and no need to). Columns has different length (`varchar(20)`,`varchar(25)`, etc.).

Update 1: This cannot be done also via loop (statements cannot be executed inside cursor).

Comment: Use show * from tablename

Comment: This fails with error. Are you sure about the command?

Comment: Anyway, I did it via writing simple script in PHP

Answer (score 1):

I use something like this type of code to generate my view automticaly using table schema. Use can modify according to your need.

```
   $sql = "show tables from DBName where Tables_in_yourtbalename = 'yourtbalename' ";
         $result = executeQuery($sql, $conn);
         $num = $result->num_rows;

    if ($num) {
        $sql = "show columns from yourtbalename where Extra != 'auto_increment'";
        $result = executeQuery($sql, $conn);
        $num2 = $result->num_rows;

        while ($r = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
            if ($r['Key'] == 'MUL' && ( preg_match("/^int/", $r['Type']) || preg_match("/^smallint/", $r['Type']) || preg_match("/^tinyint/", $r['Type']) || preg_match("/^bigint/", $r['Type']))) {

            } else if ($r['Field'] == 'status') {

            }
    }
```

Where $r['Field'] is field name and $r['Type'] provides its type. For determining maxlength use

```
  $maxlength="' . substr(str_replace(")", "", $r['Type']), 8, (strlen(str_replace(")", "",     $r['Type']))));
```